# Как вы думаете, нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

**Те знания по языку, которые я получал сначала в сельской школе, а затем( ) в гимназии, где мне удалось поучиться всего два года, были далеко не полными и, конечно, не давали мне права сказать, что я отлично знаю родной язык.**

Чем отличается эта конструкция от той, в которой этот знак действительно требуется?

Comment: Не поняла, от какой именно?

Comment: В неполном предложении.

Answer (score 1):

Я все-таки думаю, что часть "я получал (знания) сначала в сельской школе, а затем в гимназии" - это простое предложение с однородными членами. Поэтому и тире не нужно. Хотя, конечно,можно и поломать голову: а не сложное ли оно с неполной второй частью? Вопрос, конечно, интересный, только это чисто академический интерес. А среди нас пока нет синтаксиста, который бы нам все это растолковал. Да и слишком много пропущенных слов получается: и сказуемое, и союзное слово.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с [@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f): это простое предложение с однородными членами. Тире здесь не то чтобы опционально, а, на мой взгляд, даже нежелательно, так как ничем не оправдано: ни смысловым ударением (на словах *в гимназии*, которые следуют после тире), ни пропуском ЧП.

Comment: ну а разве нельзя вставить "получал" ?

Comment: Зачем же два раза одно и тоже слово? Для того и нужны однородные члены, чтобы не повторять общую информацию.

Comment: Есть гипотеза, что в придаточном (то есть в зависимом) предложении (коим является *которые я получал сначала в сельской школе, а затем( ) в гимназии*) это невозможно, так как постановка тире при пропуске одного из ЧП непременно сопровождается паузой в речи и логическим ударением на слове (словах), последующих за тире. Сравните:   
*Знания по языку я получал сначала в сельской школе, а затем - в гимназии.*   
То есть логическое (смысловое) ударение не может падать на второстепенное предложение (или на отдельные слова из этого предложения), только на главное.

Comment: Вспоминается правило о том, что в неполном предложении на месте пропущенного ЧП тире не ставится при отсутствии паузы (Я написал ему письмо, а он мне)

Comment: Ок, можно и без паузы, но смысловое ударение остается.